# Fancy table with gradient colours in borders + specific style in the footnotes?

Tags: tables, pdftex, footnotes

I actually have to separate question, the first is that I want to construct a fancy table in my document, the style of the table should look like this:

[image]

It doesn't really matter the colour as long as we will have a gradient in that specific colour. It will be so great if you can add such a style inside the table:

[image]

For my second question: Can I have the same style (the gradient colour line) in the one that's located in the footnote :

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code.

Comment: So far, I didn't wrote any code cause I don't know how the structure of the code gonna look like